# How do I write a number of the array in a user-input and get out the information of that particular array number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, user-input

I need help with schoolwork. It is an assignment I have been stuck for on a while. Here is the assignment description:

Create an array with the words "Hej", "Nej", "EJ", "Leverpastej", "42". Through a form, the user must be able to write a number and you should then display the position's words in the array. For example: enter the user 2, the word "EJ" should be displayed.

Okay, to be honest, I am so lost with this assignment that I need all help and suggestions I can get. So please help me. Maybe suggest how I can use the for loop or something the like.

Thank you!

```js
    function getFunction() {
        var rimm [];

        rimm[0] = "Hej";
        rimm[1] = "Nej";
        rimm[2] = "EJ";
        rimm[3] = "Leverpastej";
        rimm[4] = "42";

        for (var i = 0; i < rimm.length; i++) {
            if (rimm[i] == "Nej") {
                document.getElementById("skit").innerHTML += " " + rimm[i];
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("skit").innerHTML += " " + rimm[i];
            }

            document.getElementById("getnumber").value = rimm[];
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="getnumber">
<input type="button" value="Get" onclick="getFunction()">
<p>Skriv ut Skiten:</p><div id="skit"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is much simpler than you are trying to do. You can access an array element by number directly, without a loop. Just get `i` from the input, and output `rimm[i]`.

```js
var rimm = ["Hej", "Nej", "EJ", "Leverpastej", "42"];

function getFunction() {
    var i = document.getElementById("getnumber").value;
    document.getElementById("skit").textContent = rimm[i];
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="getnumber">
<input type="button" value="Get" onclick="getFunction()">
<p>Skriv ut Skiten:</p><div id="skit"></div>
```

You may want to add a check whether the number is valid and within the range of the array size. I leave this up to you.

NB: It is better to use `textContent` than `innerHTML`, as the latter is really intended for showing HTML-encoded content. Unless that is your intention, `textContent` is the way to go.

Comment: Was it just that simple? Thank you trincot!
inner.HTML is the learning level I am right now. But I will check up textContent for the future!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach you can take. I used an event handler and some validation on the user input:

```js
var words = ["Hej", "Nej", "EJ", "Leverpastej", "42"];

//Target our important elements
const userInputEl = document.querySelector('#userInput');
const outputEl = document.querySelector('#output');

//Fuction to validate the user input
const validateInput = input => {
  if (isNaN(input)) {
    outputEl.innerHTML = 'A number value is required!';
    return false;
  }

  if (input > (words.length - 1)) {
    outputEl.innerHTML = `The value must be between 0 and ${words.length - 1}`;
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};

//Add an event listener that will fire when the value in the text input is changed
userInputEl.addEventListener('change', e => {
  if (validateInput(e.target.value))
    outputEl.innerHTML = words[e.target.value];
});
```

```html
<input id="userInput" type="text">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/85rbu79d

```
<input type="number" id="getnumber">
<input type="button" value="Get" onclick="getVal()">
<p>Skriv ut Skiten:</p><div id="skit"></div>
<script>
var rimm = ["Hej", "Nej", "EJ", "Leverpastej", "42"];

function getVal() {
    var input = document.getElementById('getnumber').value,
    val = rimm[input] || 'Not an option';

    document.getElementById('skit').innerHTML = 'Value from array: ' + val;
```

}